# Date Formatting in ClosedXML

Tags: closedxml

I have date's in an excel sheet that I am reading from.
What I like to do is to force the date to be in mm/dd/yyyy
Is there a way to do this in Closed XML.

I took at a look https://closedxml.codeplex.com/documentation but could not find 
how to force or update the date to a certain format.

Comment: Should be something like `cell.Style.DateFormat.SetFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");`

Answer (score 22):

If you want to do it on Specific cell then you have to use

```
worksheet.Cell(row,column).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy";
```

and

If you want to do it on multiple cells then you have to use

```
worksheet.Range(row,column,row,column).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy";
```

Comment: Is there a way to add this on the entire cell for all ranges?

Comment: Surely, You can apply it by using a for loop.same code juss in a loop. Nothing else

Comment: I was thinking you can do this in the column header or header cell and it would just work for all ranges.  Example:  if it where in A cell.  It would do it for A1 through A infinity.  Exporting Excel in html would look like a <th> tag.

Comment: @RetroCoder No, doing apply on A1 cell it's work on only A1, and if you want to do it though A infinity - **worksheet.Colum(1).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy"**
Same for Row.

Comment: Ok, well you are the expert and I'll defer to your judgement then.  Cheers.

Comment: Yes, @Nate Pet is this a valid answer?

Comment: When I set "mm/dd/yyyy", in export is displayed with dots "mm.dd.yyyy". Why?

Comment: It is `SetFormat` now

Answer (score 2):

Cell value should come as a datetime datatype. Specific cells or between the range.

Style.DateFormat or Style.NumberFormat both will works. Use the below code:

```
ws.Range(firstCellAddress,lastCellAddress).SetDataType(XLDataType.DateTime);
ws.Range(firstCellAddress,lastCellAddress).Style.DateFormat.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy"; // "dd/mm/yyyy" or whatever format needed"

ws.Range("A","C").SetDataType(XLDataType.DateTime);
ws.Range("A","C").Style.DateFormat.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy";
```

or

```
ws.Range(rangeAddress).SetDataType(XLDataType.DateTime);
ws.Range(rangeAddress).Style.DateFormat.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy";

ws.Range("A:D").SetDataType(XLDataType.DateTime);
ws.Range("A:D").Style.DateFormat.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy";
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the question has already been aswered... but since I still lost some hours after reading this, i'd like to leave this for my future me:

Make sure you are not clearing all formats after setting the cell format. 
I had this code at the bottom of the method...

```
var range = worksheet.Range(firstCell.Address, lastCell.Address);
range.Clear(XLClearOptions.AllFormats);
```